# MySQL filter containing string count when more than two rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table (tbl_name)

```
username | app
--------------
user1      app1
user1      app2
user2      not an app
user3      not an app
user3      app3
user3      app1
user4      app1
```

I want to count users that use more than one app.

I managed to get only users that use apps quering

```
SELECT DISTINCT username, app
FROM tbl_name
WHERE app LIKE \"%@%\"
OR app LIKE \"%Desktop%\"
OR publishedapp LIKE \"%RDP%\"
ORDER BY username
```

(using WHERE and LIKE to get the cases I want to list)

this returns something like this

```
username | app
--------------
user1      app1
user1      app2
user3      app3
user3      app1
user4      app1
```

now I'm stucked trying to get, users that use more than one app, which would return in the case of having the above:

```
user
-----
user1
user3
```

users that use more than one app: 2

I've tried using count but haven't found a way to implemented properly.

Here is the code, also I don't know if I'm iterating properly trough the result

```
<?php

$servername = "servername";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT username, publishedapp
FROM tbl_name
WHERE publishedapp LIKE \"%@%\"
OR publishedapp LIKE \"%Desktop%\"
OR publishedapp LIKE \"%RDP%\"
ORDER BY username";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

for ($i=0; $i < $result->num_rows; $i++) {
  $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

  echo $i .".- ". $name1 = $row["username"] ." (". $app1 = $row["publishedapp"] ." )";

  echo "<br><br>";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what u want.. at app side

Comment: At app side I want a list the list of users that only use specific apps and the number of users that use more than one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `group by` clause along with the `group_concat`

```
SELECT username, group_concat(app), count(app)
FROM tbl_name
WHERE app LIKE \"%@%\"
OR app LIKE \"%Desktop%\"
OR publishedapp LIKE \"%RDP%\"
group by username
ORDER BY username
```

And if you need a conditional users having `app > 1` then simply use `having` after `group by` as

```
having count(app) > 1
```

Comment: it will give comma separated value at app side

Comment: I've used the following:
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT username, publishedapp, COUNT(username) as nums
FROM tbl_name
WHERE publishedapp LIKE \"%@%\"
OR publishedapp LIKE \"%Desktop%\"
OR publishedapp LIKE \"%RDP%\"
GROUP BY username";
that return number of rows that dunnot contain string but need to filter duplicates...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT username, app, COUNT(app)
FROM tbl_name
WHERE GROUP BY username HAVING COUNT(app) >= 1
```

Comment: This worked for me, it returned a list of users that have more than one filtered app, I had a bit of confusion because I wanted to be able to the list of apps too.

Comment: Hi, sorry, this is actually not what Im after, is not removing duplicated apps, so it will count users that use same app more than once